# Unable to see Facebook permission page after few attempts

Tags: android, facebook

I want to integrate Facebook with my Birthday App, so I started https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ working each step till 6.4 and I was able to see the login page with basic, since I wanted few more permissions, I added and when I am running the code its not showing the permission page , its just showing my current apps homescreen... Even now when I undo changes I made its not showing me permission page..Please help...

note: I did press login once , but since I added more permissions it should supposedly ask me again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here,*APP is Facebook App* (the id you generate for)

The "Permission Page" is shown to ask the User , **that they want this App to allow or not**.

*If they allow, in their Facebook account this app is added and the App can use this account as many ways the permissions are accepted.*

So now **once you had accepted any Application for your Account it will just do login and won't show you that "Permission Page"**

If you will try login with *another Username it will show the "Permission Page"*

Of you can also go to your **Facebook profile and remove that App** and next time **it will again show** you the "Permission Page"

> It's not like to when you change permission it will show that page,
>   its just shown once for Allow it..if Allowed already once..It wont
>   show that page again.

I have not much experience using Facebook SDK but still advice you to remove the app from your profile and login again when ever you make any changes in the permissions.

Comment: cool ...that makes lot of sense ... guess I can continue coding further without worrying about permission page..

Comment: @AndroidGirl I have not much experience using Facebook SDK but still advice you to remove the app from your profile and login again when ever you make any changes in the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will automatically ask you for more permissions. You'll need call login to re-authenticate the user so he be able to grant desired permissions.

Your code probably checks only for login state of the user without knowing which permissions he already granted (just assumption on behavior you describe, since you not provided any code sampel)...

Comment: Looks like I have to dig in deeper into the Facebook files from com_facebook_android which  I integrated in eclipse .... The code used is same as given in the above link tutorial, I have just added facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"email", "friends_about_me", "friends_birthday"},.... extra permisions

Comment: have you creted your app @facebook site